# How to solve the definite integral using u-substitution? (difficult)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have been trying to solve the following problem all day?

$$∫\frac{(9x^4\cdot\sin(9x))}{(1+x^8)}dx$$

I made

$$u=\sin(9x)$$

but I'm not really getting anywhere with that. Any kind of feedback or guidance would be very appreciated!

EDIT: the interval is [-pi/2, pi/2]

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+9x%5E4*sin(9x)%2F(1%2Bx%5E8)) gets a real mess, so I doubt you will get there.

Comment: The integral can be expressed in “sine integral” and “cosine integral” by WolframAlpha. These are two special integrals. Did you miss the interval of the integral? ($\int_0^\pi$ or $\int_0^\infty$)

Comment: yes actually, the interval is [-pi/2,pi/2]. I need to find the definite integral in this interval..@WongAustin

Comment: **After your edit** : do you really thing that you *need to find the definite integral* for $\int_{-a}^{+a} f(x)\,dx$ considering this $f(x)$ ?

Comment: yeah... is there something im not seeing? hint please?@ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: There is something that you are not seeing, for sure !

Comment: oh darn it, the function is odd so it will be 0 within that interval...wow im not proud of how long that took me, thank you for the guidance! @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Glad you found it ! This is really the first thing to check when you face $\int_{-a}^{+a} f(x)\,dx$ with **any** $f(x)$. Now, please : when you ask a question, provide all the elements. My work became just ridiculous as soon as you gave the bounds. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This was written before the edit told that the integral has bounds.**

This is a true monster, for sure.

What you *could* do is to use partial fraction decomposition to write $$\frac{9x^4}{1+x^8}=\sum_{i=1}^8 \frac{A_i}{x-r_i}$$ (have fun !) and then the problem *reduces* to 
$$\int\frac{(9x^4\cdot\sin(9x))}{(1+x^8)}\,dx=\sum_{i=1}^8 A_i\int \frac{\sin(9x)}{x-r_i}\,dx=\sum_{i=1}^8 A_i I_i$$ Now, consider $$I_i=\int \frac{\sin(9x)}{x-r_i}\,dx$$ and change variable $x=y+r_i$ to get $$I_i=\int \frac{\sin(9(y+r_i))}{y}\,dy=\cos(9r_i)\int \frac{\sin(9y)}{y}\,dy+\sin(9r_i)\int \frac{\cos(9y)}{y}\,dy$$ Using now $y=\frac z9$,we get $$I_i=\cos(9r_i)\int \frac{\sin(z)}{z}\,dz+\sin(9r_i)\int \frac{\cos(z)}{z}\,dz$$ that is to say $$I_i=\cos(9r_i)\,\text{Si}(z)+\sin(9r_i)\,\text{Ci}(z)$$ where appear the sine and cosine integrals.

Then, the real mess given by Wolfram Alpha as early commented by Ross Millikan.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I don't even know how to do what you just did there, yet...but someday :). i edited the post, I'm supposed to be finding the definite integral [-pi/2,pi/2] ...i didn't included at first because i didn't think it would matter but now im not sure...

Comment: @rhoward. Have a look to my comment, please.